# One-way ANOVA in R using summary data

Tags: r, anova

I want to perform One-way ANOVA in R. I do not have the raw data, but only the mean, standard error and size of each group (there are three groups). If I understand correctly, the `ind.oneway.second` command in the `rpsychi` package is relevant only when the groups are the same size. Is there a way to perform One-way ANOVA in R when the groups are not the same size?

Comment: ind.oneway.second(m, sd, n,  unbiased = TRUE, contr = NULL, sig.level = 0.05, digits = 3) Why not specify n?

Comment: So you have 3 observations? I.e. the means in each group, and their deviations? Or did I miss interpret?

Comment: `n` can not get vector with different values. When I try to do it, I get the next error: `Error in delta.upper + dfb : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. Again, for each group I have only the following data: mean, standard error and size. I do not have the raw data (observations).

Comment: @Pini, did you ever solve this error message?

Answer (score 1):

Can use for group of different size.

```
library(rpsychi)
mu<-c(0.75,0.77,0.72,0.85)
mu.sd<-c(0.16,0.11,0.12,0.10)
mu.n<-c(13,22,42,28)
(mu.ind.anova <- ind.oneway.second(mu,mu.sd,mu.n))
```